# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. Windows Phone while using files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, serialization, async-await, isolatedstoragefile

i'm getting a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. " message when im trying to save a list on the Windows Phone.

Scenario:

When clicked on the FavoriteButton, the system will check if the item is already a favorite.

The next step is to call the Load method. This will return a list with favorites.

When the item is favorite I will remove it from the list, otherwise i will add it.

Final step is to save the new list with my Save method.

When executing this code i get the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED

I've looked around and saw that it could be the manifest capabilities. So i have checked them all just to be sure. After trying again I still get the exception!

What must i do? code below:

```
     private async void favoriteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_progressIndicator.IsVisible == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Boolean isFavorite = Settings.GetValueOrDefault<Boolean>(currentArtist.id, false);
                ArtistSaving favorite = new ArtistSaving(currentArtist.id, currentArtist.name, currentArtist.shortBio);
                artistList = await Task.Run(() => Utils.Load<ArtistSaving>());
                if (isFavorite == true)
                {
                    artistList.Remove(favorite);
                    displayDeletePopup();
                    Settings.AddOrUpdateValue(currentArtist.id, false);
                    await Task.Run(() => Utils.Save<ArtistSaving>(artistList));
                }
                else
                {
                    artistList.Add(favorite);
                    displayXamlPopup();
                    Settings.AddOrUpdateValue(currentArtist.id, true);
                     await Task.Run(() =>  Utils.Save<ArtistSaving>(artistList));
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Favorite button click

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> Load<T>()
    {
        // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
        var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(JSONFILENAME,
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));

        var myStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        ObservableCollection<T> myObj = (ObservableCollection<T>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);

        if (myObj == null)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<T>();
        }
        return myObj;
    }
```

This is the Load method

```
 public static async void Save<T>(ObservableCollection<T> obj)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));

        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
            JSONFILENAME, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        }
    }
```

and this was the Save method

EDIT -- SOLUTION

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> Load<T>()
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> myObj = null;
        // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
        var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(JSONFILENAME,
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));

        using (var myStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            myObj = (ObservableCollection<T>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
            if (myObj == null)
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<T>();
            }
            return myObj;
        }


    }
```

Comment: There's no need for "isFavorite == true". isFavorite is already a boolean, so you can just use if (isFavorite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the file is still locked from when you read from it. Modify your Load method like this to release the file lock:

```
using (var myStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    ObservableCollection<T> myObj = (ObservableCollection<T>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius ! This did the trick ! updated my question with solution. Many thanks, could you explain why this "using" is exactly doing?

Comment: Sure thing!  The Stream class inherits from IDisposable. What this means is that once the object is constructed, it will hang around until you call the Dispose() method. The using method will automatically call the Dispose() method which causes the object to go out of scope and free the resource. Check out [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) for a great outline on why Disposable object exist.

Comment: No problem, I went through all of these issues last year :)